# In what cases is it acceptable to add multiple answers to same question?

Tags: discussion, answers

So I recently noticed that I can add more than one answers for same question! Does each answer act separately when it comes to vote count? Meaning, if both of my answer gets up votes, will I get rep increased for both? If yes, then what are the cases when it is acceptable to have multiple answers on same question?

Example, this (https://writing.stackexchange.com/a/44344/22084) beautiful answer's each point could be a separate answer and separate votes or its not a good practice to do the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write multiple answers and each answer can gain its own reputation for you. You will of course be limited by the rep cap of 200 per day.

As for when it is appropriate, two such situations that I have seen it used for on multiple sites are:

- When one posts answers that are mutually exclusive. That said a question that elicits mutually exclusive answers that are equally valid are usually (but not always) POB(Primarily Opinion Based).
- Breaking up extraordinarily long posts. Ridiculously long Facebook feed length answers get hard to read. People may give up part way through. The use of markup is your friend in such situations to add some visual variety, but it isn't always enough. By breaking up the answer and making it more reader friendly, you are doing everyone a favor.

I wouldn't write two answers lightly though. The first question I would ask myself is: **Is there a reason to separate these answers?** If not, then don't. If yes, whether your reason is one I listed or one of your own proceed with caution. No matter how good your reasoning you run the risk of catching downvotes from people who are voting on your perceived gaming the system rather than your content. It is also important that each answer adds value and can stand on its own. **If the other answer is removed, will the answer still stand? And vice versa?**

Comment: I think instead of just "contradictory," if the answers are using different strategies, then that may work.  Perhaps one answer is based on history of language and sounds, and another is based mostly on examples in genre fiction... it's practically like 2 separate people are answering, since these are two separate paths.  I'm wondering if I lose upvotes sometimes because I include several such paths in a single answer, and even with formatting, people may just skip after a bit. (I'm thinking of the non-silly-fake-cussing one.)    So someone may want to upvote my middle part, but not 2 others.

Comment: @April yes I think that happens. I know I will refrain from upvoted if I find one aspect of the answer too problematic. If it's bad enough I will even downvote an otherwise acceptable answer. (I'm not speaking directly of the answer you mentioned)

Comment: I admit, most of my writing here is "first draft" -- no edits, so the order may indeed be a little chaotic, and the best parts are near the end.  This might just indicate that I should edit my answers if I feel a good "core" is being neglected.   (feel free to do that to mine, if I'm rambling.)